How to handle errors thrown by @bufbuild/protobuf
I am trying to understand how I can get useful information from the errors thrown by the @bufbuild/protobuf package in NodeJS.
Most errors look like this, which doesn't contain any useful information where to look in my code. Event the stack trace already doesn't include any files of my own code.
Error: cannot decode message ... from JSON: undefined
    at readMessage (file://.../node_modules/@bufbuild/protobuf/dist/esm/from-json.js:115:15)
    at readMessageField (file://.../node_modules/@bufbuild/protobuf/dist/esm/from-json.js:242:5)
    at readField (file://.../node_modules/@bufbuild/protobuf/dist/esm/from-json.js:163:13)
    at readMessage (file://.../node_modules/@bufbuild/protobuf/dist/esm/from-json.js:136:13)
    at readListField (file://.../node_modules/@bufbuild/protobuf/dist/esm/from-json.js:221:17)
    at readField (file://.../node_modules/@bufbuild/protobuf/dist/esm/from-json.js:166:13)
    at readMessage (file://.../node_modules/@bufbuild/protobuf/dist/esm/from-json.js:136:13)
    at readMessageField (file://.../node_modules/@bufbuild/protobuf/dist/esm/from-json.js:242:5)
    at readField (file://.../node_modules/@bufbuild/protobuf/dist/esm/from-json.js:163:13)
    at readMessage (file://.../node_modules/@bufbuild/protobuf/dist/esm/from-json.js:136:13)

I mostly use the fromJson and toJson functions which already give a better message description than create. What is everybody else doing to get a meaningful message.
